# Webpack not finding image paths after removing the asset pipeline in rails 5.1.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

I am working with rails 5.1.7. and trying to migrate from the asset pipeline to webpacker, I have already run rake assets:precompile

I am getting this message:

```
Webpacker can't find logo.png in /***/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-a5be4c0a9f54fffa5cb7.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-a5be4c0a9f54fffa5cb7.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-a5be4c0a9f54fffa5cb7.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-a5be4c0a9f54fffa5cb7.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That's after setting my images in `app/javascript/images` in which I verified logo.png is there.

The line prompting this issue is:

```
   <%= link_to asset_pack_path('logo.png', alt: 'logo', width: 150), locale_root_path, class: 'logo'%>
```

**If I just simply remove that line it will lead me to the path of another different image that is also in that folder (app/javascript/image).**

I have this extract to configure the image path in my app/javascript/packs/application.js file is:

```
const images = require.context('../images', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Webpack needs to be configured to compile your images:**

In your `app/javascript` directory, create an images folder, and place the `logo.png` inside.

`image_tag` has been changed to `image_pack_tag` now that your images are being compiled with webpack. However, by default you would have to pass in the entire image path each time, beginning with `media/`, followed by the path from your webpack source path, which is defined in you `webpacker.yml` config file. For example:

`<%= image_pack_tag 'media/images/logo.png', alt: 'logo', width: 150%>`

To solve this, you can use `require.context`:

In your webpage entry point, by default this is located in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`, you should add the following line:

```
const images = require.context("../images", true);
```

To access the logo image in your view, you can now use:

`<%= image_pack_tag 'logo.png', alt: 'logo', width: 150%>`

Comment: Hi, I have this configuration and I have implemented "image_pack_tag" but I have the exact same problem. (Now the image giving error does not appear in the public/manifest.js file but other images do appear there

Comment: Hi, now it is working, the path to the images in the manifest.js file were showing as "media/image/logo.png" so just adding "logo.png" instead of /images/logo worked (it was working also if I added media/image/logo.png

Comment:  Happy to have helped

Answer (score 1):

First you need to tell webpack that you want to use this image file, so (for example) in your app/javascript/packs/application.js file put:

```js
require.context('../images', true)
```

Then confirm that the images are indeed compiled into the manifest.
then to put this image into the link, try (I'm not totally sure webpacker can deal with this) `image_pack_tag('media/images/logo.png')`

Give it a try and let us know what happens.

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to point out that this is already configured on m app/javascript/packs/application.js file. I will update the question accordingly.